# Remove One drive login prompt

Tags: onedrive

I'm regularly getting prompted by onedrive to login and then it shows the prompt to log into my former schools office 365. of course I don't have an account there anymore and have removed the account from my laptop but one drive keeps bothering me.

How can I get rid of that prompt?

EDIT: I want to keep onedrive for my personal account

Comment: Did you remove the accont from the list accounts in Settings?

Comment: You can uninstall One Drive in Programs and Settings

Comment: Run Credential Manager and search for your account (or OneDrive) in Web Credentials or Windows Credentials and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try uninstalling OneDrive? Otherwise you should see if the account still exists under Settings > Accounts > Access work or school. If not, you may be able to choose to log off from the account. Sometimes on the sign in page at the bottom there is a link to choose a different account. A last option is to look for all folders that contain data from OneDrive under AppData.

I think simply uninstalling OneDrive will be the simplest option, normally you can uninstall it from settings under Apps > Installed apps.

If you somehow can't uninstall OneDrive from settings, you can try using the command prompt to invoke the installer:

1. Press Win+R on your keyboard.
2. Type in `taskkill /f /im OneDrive.exe` and press enter.
3. Type in `%SystemRoot%\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe /uninstall` and press enter.
4. Type in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe /uninstall` and of course press enter.

Comment: You can uninstall OneDrive from Windows 10, it's not like Microsoft Edge where Microsoft is forcing you to use it. Even on [their website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-off-disable-or-uninstall-onedrive-f32a17ce-3336-40fe-9c38-6efb09f944b0) they tell you how to uninstall it. I can confirm this on 3 Windows devices I own, all running different editions and different versions, but I can uninstall OneDrive just fine. To make you happy I have added a method to force uninstall under any condition.

Answer (score 0):

I sugges you chek the related registry keys. Before you modify them, please remember to [back up the registry for restoration](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322756) in case problems occur.

1.

Exit OneDrive by right clicking on the OneDrive icon > Click Exit or     Quit OneDrive. Open the Registry Editor by searching regedit > OK.

Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > OneDrive >    Accounts > BusinessX.

"X" is the amount of Business accounts that you have logged into    previously. Find the specific one by looking at the UserEmail value.    After you find the correct one, delete the entire folder    (BusinessX).

2.

Navigate to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > CLSID. Inside the folder, search (CTRL + F) to find keyword: OneDrive.

Find next until you find the one (string subfoler like ) that has the "OneDrive – xxx" (The name which is related to the school account) as the Default value.

Then delete this string subfoler.